# I delete cookies file in chrome but i'm still logged in after I restart Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, cookies

I'm using `linux` and `google chrome` as browser. I know that cookeis are stored at `/home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies`.

I deleted this file but it seems like when I restart Chrome and try to browse for example `facebook`, website logs me in. So I got little confused why do websites still authenticating me even if I don't have cookies file.
**P.S** Its not about that i don't know how to clear cookies. its about that I don't understand the concept.Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the cookie file is re-written from RAM when Chrome exits? Try clearing the cookies the usual way, i.e. using Ctrl+Shift+Del. Also, StackOverflow is a programming site; for general computer issues, there's SuperUser.com ; I have voted to move your question there.

Comment: when I exit chrome I check folder and there is not cookies file...

Comment: Either clean ~/.cache/google-chrome or go to Options and then within the Personal Stuff tab click on the button "Clear browsing data.."

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1002762/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105947/i-delete-cookies-file-in-chrome-but-im-still-logged-in-after-i-restart-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main reasons why your browser ist still authenticating you: You may have not deleted the cookies (for example when deleting the file while Chrome was still running). Check that the Cookies actually have been deleted: In Chrome open the menu, then choose Settings, click "Show Advanced Settings", in the "Privacy" section, click "Content settings". The "Cookies" section should show them (or not).

Not all autologins operate through cookies. Chrome can store passwords and login-pages can still sit in the cache. So try this: Check that the passwords for the sites in question are not saved: In Chrome open the menu, then choose Settings, click "Show Advanced Settings", under "Passwords and forms", click "Manage passwords". Empty the cache: In Chrome open the menu, then choose History. Now you can "Clear Browsing Data".